# Trace/BPT trap: 5 from ruby / rails / cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber

I have a rails 3.2.8 app with rspec, capybara, and cucumber.  When I run my cucumber tests, I now see them start up but soon it does with:

```
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

e.g.

```
cucumber
Using the default profile...
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
Feature: User submits a swinfo query
  In order to look up the entries for a given Defect or other item, I
  submit a query in the swinfo form.

  @javascript @webkit
  Scenario: Submit swinfo query for a defect via browser # features/user_swinfo_request.feature:6
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Is there a way to at least get a stack trace for this so I have a clue as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the trap was coming when ldap loaded a C extension after another extension was loaded.  I changed my application.rb file to load ldap first and that worked around the issue.

I never did figure out how to get a stack trace back.  I tracked it down through trail and error.

Hope this helps someone